# only checks first and last character

Tags: java

I am new to java and am trying to create a palindrome word program, to check if the word backwards is the same.

```
public static void isPalindromeWord(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a word to check: ");
        String word = input.next().toLowerCase();
        String reversed = new StringBuffer(word).reverse().toString();
        int len = word.length();
        for(int x = 0; x < len ; x++){
            if(word.charAt(x) == reversed.charAt(x)){
                System.out.println("True");
            }else{
                System.out.println("False");
            }
        }

    }
```

Please excuse if I've done anything wrong, I have only started learning today.

My problem is :

1. With the current it outputs True for something such as "otto" which is a palindrome. But it also does True for "oplko" which isn't. So I know that it only checks the first and last letters but I thought that with the for loop it will go through each letter?

Can someone be kind enough to explain where I am going wrong and suggest how to fix it? The reason I am using a for loop is because the task is requiring me to do so.

Comment: You have the `word` and you have `reversed` now all you have to do is check that `word.equals(reversed)` - why are you comparing characters ?

Comment: @alfasin the task I am doing said to use a loop. Sorry i should include that in the main questikon.

Comment: Should you break out of the for-loop once you hit non-equal character?

Answer (score 2):

You are very close to the solution. Since you have already reversed the string you can check if they are equal

```
new StringBuffer(word).reverse().equals(word);
```

Edit: Added one more solution for using loop

What you are doing in the loop is mostly correct. You are getting `True` for `oplko` is because you are not exiting the loop when the `word.charAt(x) == reversed.charAt(x)` condition fails. This can be fixed by

```
public static void isPalindromeWord() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a word to check: ");
    String word = input.next().toLowerCase();
    String reversed = new StringBuffer(word).reverse().toString();
    int len = word.length();
    for (int x = 0; x < len; x++) {
        if (word.charAt(x) != reversed.charAt(x)) {
            System.out.println("False");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("True");
}
```

Comment: the task i'm doing is to practice loops, and so I already thought of that but should've said in the main question,sorry.

Comment: NP, i added one more approach for using loop

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of ways to do what you want (including Anthony C's very elegant answer), but here is a simple fix to make yours work :

```
public static void isPalindromeWord(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a word to check: ");
    String word = input.next().toLowerCase();
    //you don't really need to get a reverse here
    //String reversed = new StringBuffer(word).reverse().toString();
    int len = (int)(word.length() / 2);//only check half (and not evnt the middle one for odd numbers

    boolean isPalindrom = true;
    for(int x = 0; x < len ; x++){
        if(word.charAt(x) != word.charAt(word.length() - 1 - x)){
            isPalindrom = false;
            //at least one difference, this is not a palindrome
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isPalindrom)
       System.out.println("True");//the for wasn't broken
    else
       System.out.println("False");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void isPalindromeWord(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a word to check: ");
    String word = input.next();
    String reversed = input.next();

    char c[]=word.toLowerCase().toCharArray(); 
    char d[]=reversed.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

    if(word.length() != reversed.length()) System.out.print("False ");
    Arrays.sort(c);
    Arrays.sort(d);

    if(Arrays.equals(c,d)) System.out.print("True ");
    else System.out.print("False ");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to describe where you have a mistake. You are writing in console on every step of loop, doesn't matter which result of comparing do you have.

```
    boolean isPolindrom = true;
    for(int x = 0; x < len ; x++){
        isPolindrom = (word.charAt(x) == reversed.charAt(x)); //compare chars and store result into variable
        if (!isPolindrom) { //if chars are different break a loop, because word is already not a polindrom
             break; 
        }
    }

    System.out.println(isPolindrom);  //output result
```

Solution from @AnthonyC is really better